# I am getting "myApp stopped working" after installig my WPF(+telerik) application

Tags: wpf, deployment, telerik, installshield, advanced-installer

I created a WPF application using telerik control suite (WPF telerik controls and ORM access control) and SQL Express R2 2008 in VS 2012.

Then I created its setup files (using install shield LE and also Advanced Installer) which works on my win7 system, properly () .but when I install the setup file on any other win7 system, it doesn’t work( I am getting this error: “MyAPP has stopped working”).

I installed .NET framework and SQL Express R2 2008(the service’s status is running) and I also copied the mdf and ldf files related to the database in right path that specified in app.xaml.

When I install my setup files, it just copy my project’s debug folder (contains the telerik control dll files, the dll file related to my ORM access control project, built exe file and etc.). I think that’s enough. Isn’t it?

**Edit**:

The project's Solution's Explorer:

[image]

- \bin\Debug

[image: - \bin\Debug]

I have no idea what to do.

I would really really appreciate any hint or comment.

Regards,

Hiva

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very general answer although without knowing the details of your project it's the best I can do. I remember when I was creating an app using telerik controls, when I went to publish it I was getting errors in the with the assembly which was a result of including the obj / Debug / Release folders in my project. I tried everything that people listed to get rid of the errors but the only thing that helped was creating a new project, copying in the code and NEVER including(Never right clicking and hitting include in project) those folders in my project.

Is it working when you debug it?
Could you please let me know what steps you are taking to publish the app ?

Comment: Thanks kgritt, Never including what folders? Debug/Release folders or the Code folder?
I have any problem with debugging or telerik assemblies. the problem is my applications only work on my system, not any other system. even when I copy my Debug folder to any other directory, it works.I'm sorry, I'm a newbie on windows application deployment.

i added some details to the post.

Comment: I created an Advanced Installer project in VS2012(as you see in the picture),
I added all the files in Debug folder to it.
and I did some other setting like setting install parameters and etc.

Comment: I used this tutorial to deployment my application:
http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html